# Is it possible to install Python on Unix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix

I have managed to find Unix OS source and I intend to study it in terms of automation but the problem is that installing python on AT&T Systems Unix V seems more than impossible. Is there any way to download python on Unix such that it works just as it would on a MS Windows, MacOS or Linux?

I tried automating Unix with ShellScript but it seems that ShellScript does not have the ease and scope of Python. I am trying to study the working of AT&T Systems Unix V and I installed it on Virtual Box.

Comment: What is your actual goal with using such an ancient variant of Unix? It does not adhere to modern standards, and the last official release was SVR5 in 1997, so it's about to turn 25 this year. It won't run on any modern hardware without emulation.

Comment: My goal is to study the working of the Operating systems and unix is the parent of major Operating Systems that exist today. I used Virtual Box to provide Emulation as it failed to support genric computer hardware.

Comment: You would have to compile it yourself, of course.  You might have to go back in history to get an older version of Python, since your C compiler is going to be antique.  You would have awk, of course.

Comment: Isn't there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Read this article](https://docs.python.org/3/using/unix.html) from python documentation, it is about installing Python On *Unix based* Systems.
The following command will work on systems like Unix Or BSD

```
pkg_add -r python

pkg_add ftp://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/4.2/packages/<insert your architecture here>/python-<version>.tgz
```